# How does ground control monitor the docking of ships to the ISS?

Tags: iss, docking

What kind of instruments are currently used, when ground control is monitoring a docking of new ship (or) segment to the ISS.

Do they monitor it at all?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurs_(docking_system) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TriDAR and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TORU...

Comment: In Mission Control (MCC-H and MCC-M) a bunch of workstations display ranges, attitudes, angles, velocities and other data. Mission control specialists use their eyes and brains.

Comment: There are multiple translated and commented videos of docking on youtube (such as this one  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRGl7MZJVno video of Soyuz TMA-06M automated docking using Kurs working in TORU mode).

Comment: @horsh - either automated or TORU. TORU is the manual one.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you, that's a leftover, Soyuz TMA-06M was going in automated mode. Initially I  wanted to post this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLbJqjASD60 video of Progress M-01M going in TORU mode, but then decided to go with Soyuz TMA-06M as a bit more spectacular and with enough suspense.

Comment: Of course they monitor the whole progress. It's their mission. Isn't it? For instance, take [Soyuz](http://youtu.be/vJevzhynfC0). There's a camera on both ISS and Soyuz (filming each other) providing live telecast of what's happening out there. BTW, what do you mean by *"instruments"*. IMO, Ground control uses a lot of computers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES** it is monitored by [ground control station](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_C._Kraft_Jr._Mission_Control_Center)  but it is controlled by the astronaut in ISS or sometimes it may be automated

[space vision system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Space_Vision_System) which uses camera to capture 2D images and then convert it to 3D images by using computer . And with the help of this system astronaut uses the robotic arm . but this system has certain problem

[TRIdar](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TriDAR) is a  relative navigation vision system which uses a 3D camera and thermal imaging (LASER based)

> This laser-
>   based system tracks retro
>   reflectors located on the ISS
>   to provide bearing, range and
>   closing rate information. While
>   reliable, target based systems
>   have operational limitations as
>   targets must be installed on
>   target payloads. This is not
>   always practical or even
>   possible.  For example,
>   servicing existing satellites
>   that don’t have reflectors
>   installed would require a
>   targetless tracking capability.

[TORU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TORU)

> TORU has two joysticks which
>   can be used to manually fly
>   the ship.The left joystick is
>   used to control the movement
>   of the ship and the right
>   joystick is used to control its
>   orientation. The system also
>   includes a camera that is
>   mounted on the docking
>   spacecraft and provides visual
>   feedback when the spacecraft
>   is remotely controlled from
>   the station to that it is
>   docking. TORU also transfers
>   sounds from the spacecraft
>   that may provide indirect
>   information about the docking
>   process

[kurs docking system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurs_%28docking_system%29) it is used in ISS and MIR when a vehicle approach the space station it will emit radar pulses from
multiple antennas and change in the strength between
the antennas allows the
system to compute relative
position, attitude, and
approach rate.